# How to tell NetworkGateway to not use an Ethernet profile as default gateway

Tags: fedora, routing, networkmanager

I want to use wifi to connect to the internet

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.37.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

This is the effect of the automatic configuration through NetworkManager. So far so good.

The problem is: once I add an ethernet connection with a manual IP, I get the following effect

```
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
 default         169.254.100.100 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s20u2u3
 default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
 169.254.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s20u2u3
 192.168.37.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

Now I cannot connect to the internet anymore.

I guess the question is: how to configure the ethernet profile to not set a default gateway?

I am on Fedora25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try editing the init-scripts in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.  If one doesn't exist for the profile you can create it manually via terminal; or, if you go to "Add Profile" via *Settings*.  Then, add/edit the following:

```
DEFROUTE=no
```

You might also have to add/edit the following:

```
PEERROUTES=no
```

#### Using nmcli

Alternatively, [using the NetworkManager commandline tool](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html#sec-Connecting_to_a_Network_Using_nmcli), `nmcli`, do:

```
nmcli con modify eth0 ipv4.never-default yes
```

**Note:** `eth0` is the ***name of the connection*** NOT the name of the interface!
To get the name of the connection you want/need, list the active profiles

```
# nmcli con show
NAME       UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE 
eth0     c0ab4c5a-0edb-a1b4-2a33-dba7a31033e  802-3-ethernet     eth0
```

You can access the nmcli editor via

```
 # nmcli con edit eth0
nmcli> describe ipv4.never-default

=== [never-default] ===
[NM property description]
If TRUE, this connection will never be the default connection for this IP type, meaning it will never be assigned the default route by NetworkManager.
```

For additional information on `nmcli`, and specific examples using it, take a look at https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/nmcli-examples.html